# Opening up iTerm / Terminal with commands by default.

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, gruntjs

My current use of iTerm is the following everytime:

```
- Open up 
- cd into my project folder

- open up another tab
- cd into my project folder
- Grunt Watch

- open up another tab
- SSH into live server
```

This is getting a bit tedious now, is there a simple way to make a one click for all of this to be done? I remember back in the windows days you could create custom command prompt files so it would open up and you could just double click it like an app.

Is there anyway I can do this? I have looked at the profiles and I don't think I can do what I am after with that.

Just need pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I can't test this but looks like the API is able to handle what you want. Did you look at (particularly the last) example [here](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/AppleScript)? Another alternative is running tmux in iTerm which has easily configurable startup.

Comment: I never even knew AppleScript existed... looks to be able to do what I need though so all good! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using iTerm2, there is a feature called [Arrangements](http://iterm2.com/documentation-menu-items.html) (see the last entry on the page). With this, you can set iTerm to open a series of profiles (which can be set to run a command at startup, start in a specific directory, run a certain shell, etc.).

It seems that creating one profile for working in a directory, a second for the Grunt Watch, and a third to SSH should be trivial, and once the arrangement is saved, it can be recalled with the press of a hotkey (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on my install). You can also set this to save [split-pane windows](http://iterm2.com/features.html) if you don't want a separate window for each of these tasks.